# Когда выбирать реляционную БД, а когда не реляционную?

Tags: mysql, база-данных, mysqli, nosql

Пишу сайт. Подразумевается большое количество записей разного размера. Подумал о том, что при большом объёме записей БД будет долго обрабатывать запрос, поэтому надо её раскинуть на несколько серверов. но вычитал, что реляционные БД плохо масштабируются и для больших объемов данных используют не реляционные.

---

**подВопрос:**
Как поступить: пока не заморачиваться над этим и потом, при необходимости, перенести данные в не реляционную БД ИЛИ выбрать реляционную/не реляционную БД ?

Comment: «Большое количество записей» — это сколько?

Comment: Реляционные БД плохо масштабируются? А пацаны из Hadoop-то и не знают.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Подумал о том, что при большом объёме записей БД будет долго обрабатывать запрос

Планирование не может начинаться с "подумал", боттлнеки всегда бывают в иных местах. Реляционки спокойно работают с миллионами записей.

> поэтому надо её раскинуть на несколько серверов. но вычитал, что реляционные БД плохо масштабируются

Тут у меня опять претензия в ту же степь. Вы не знаете, что именно вы вычитали. Они действительно плохо масштабируются из-за того, что (по крайней мере у большинства) есть только одна модель master-slaves, которая упирается в мастер по скорости записи (поправьте, если есть популярные движки с многочисленными мастерами). В любом случае в базе данных не должно быть тяжелых подсчетов - если вы считаете количество записей в БД, то это должно рассчитываться внутри БД и кэшироваться на уровне приложения, если вы рассчитываете аналитику, то тут БД уже ничего считать не должна.

В общем, у меня большие сомнения, что вам нужна масштабируемая система. Что до нереляционок, то их нельзя выбрать просто потому что "лучше масштабируются" - их только основных типов четыре штуки под свои задачи (вряд ли вы будете использовать key-value или графовую БД). Что до масштабирования, то есть row-column (т.е. хранение данных практически как в SQL) Cassandra, которая шардит данные по узлам и имеет практически линейную масштабируемость, т.е. добавление сервера в кластер из N серверов обеспечивает практически `100 * (1 / N + 1)` процентов прироста производительности. Если есть знание кассандры, то делать проект на чем-то другом я не вижу смысла (единственная претензия - отсутствие готовых утилит для миграций, но это, надеюсь, изменится), классические реляционки как концепция по факту уже умерли - они, конечно, останутся, но в узком применении, и ближайшие N лет их популярность будет снижаться.

Comment: Благодарю за комментарий. Ответ на свой вопрос я получил, спасибо)  **Реляционки спокойно работают с миллионами записей** - и это также хотел узнать, спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Во первых, выбор типа базы данных мало зависит от количества записей, а от архитектуры приложения, специфики данных и многих других факторов.

Во вторых, реляционные базы данных отлично масштабируются. Например Кассандра способна обрабатывать ~2к запросов в секунду и предоставляет горизонтальное масштабирование. По моим наблюдениям в крупных проектах(миллионы записей в день) отдают предпочтение как раз кассандре.

В третьих, не все NoSQL базы данных подходят для работы с большим количеством объектов. Тот же RavenDB совсем не подходит для большого количества маленьких записей. Но если объединить большое количество этих маленьких записей в один документ, то эта база прекрасно справится.

В целом сама постановка вопроса говорит о том, что вы плаваете в вопросе.
Для работы с BigData не достаточно сделать правильного выбора базы данных, нужно еще грамотно реализовать архитектуру. В противном случае у вас будут проблемы даже при использовании самой подходящего инструмента для вашей задачи. Рекомендую почитать литературу посвященную проектированию баз данных.

Answer (score -1):

1. Если хочешь всех удивить возьми *nosql*
2. Если хочешь блеснуть знанием старины возьми [сетевую БД](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%A1%D0%A3%D0%91%D0%94)
3. Если хочешь получить благодарность с того света от [бабушки Ады](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%B4%D0%B0_(%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)) - возьми [иерархическую БД](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85)
4. Ну и наконец, если хочешь написать что-нибудь стоящее возьми реляционную БД